# Execute function on declaration

Tags: python

In javascript, we have an option to declare function and execute it immediately after(like this)

```
(function toBeExecutedImmediately() {
    // Code
}());
```

Is there any similar in python?

Comment: Can you explain what problem you're trying to solve by using IIFEs in Python? AFAIK, the problem that they solve in JS (preventing pollution of the global namespace) isn't an issue in Python.

Comment: @Brian there is none. I just learning python and I wanted to know how do I implement something known from js.

Comment: @Brian *exactly*. And I think in modern JS with `strict` it isn't a problem anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The literal equivalent would be this, or something similar depending on the parameters:

```
(lambda: None)()
```

There's no reason to do this though. IIFEs aren't a common pattern in Python.

Also note, this can only contain a single expression. If you want to allow statements, you'd need `def`.

Comment: So basically, I can use IIFE as is only on lambda expressions, but if I want to use it on `def`, I need to create a decorator?

Comment: @myfishnameisqwerty Yes, you must use a lambda for this. Note that Fatin's solution is kind of "cheating". His code is basically the same as `def _(): print('I execute immediately'); _ = evalfn(_);`. It's really just syntactic sugar for a full definition that's called after. That's also kind of awkward because the `_` name is bound, called, then re-overwritten with `None`, so now you have a `_` symbol in scope without a useable value.

Comment: @myfishnameisqwerty you dont require a decorator. In any case, you can always just do `def foo ...` then call foo: `foo()` then remove the name from the namespace: `del foo` but all of this would seem odd in python.

Answer (score 5):

yes, there are many ways in python function to be self-executed. One way is>>>

```
evalfn = lambda f: f()

@evalfn
def _():
    print('I execute immediately')
```

Comment: This is fundamentally not different from just calling the function afterwards

Answer (score 4):

This should be the Python equivalent:

```
def toBeExecutedImmediately():
    # Code
toBeExecutedImmediately()
```

Comment: This is a regular function declaration and then the call. I want to call on the declaration.

Comment: @myfishnameisqwerty function definition statements are *statements*, you can't call the result of them because they do not have a result, they work by side effect. `lambda` expressions are expressions, they evaluate to a function object, so you can just call them